# Get bash script to open terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

In Windows when I double-click a Batch script, it will automatically open a terminal window and show me what's happening. If I were to double-click a bash script in Linux, a terminal window does not open to show me what is happening; it runs in the background. I have seen that one can use one script to launch another script in a new terminal window with `x-terminal-emulator -e "./script.sh"`, but is there any bash command I can put into the same (one) `script.sh` so that it will open a terminal and show me what's happening (or if I need to answer y/n questions)?

Comment: I don't know if this would work, but maybe `if ! [ -t 0 ]; then exec x-terminal-emulator -e "./script.sh"; fi`?

Comment: @Edward : What do you mean by "double-click in Linux"? WHERE do you double click (i.e. which application is open to show you the script), and which Window Manager are you using?

Comment: Heh, or maybe `#!/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -ebash script.sh` as the first line of the script. This might be an awful hack.

Comment: @user1934428 Anywhere like the Desktop, Nautilus, or totalcommander type managers.

Comment: @melpomene I think you got it. Hm. Will the code that follows that line be executed twice with that?

Comment: @Edward : With Window managers, I mean something like KDE or Gnome. If i understand you correctly, you need an operation which says: "Open this file WITH program XXX", where your XXX happens to be a Terminal program of your choice.

Comment: @melpomene: The problem with that is that in Linux the kernel passes the whole line after the first "word" as a single argument. Also, `x-terminal-emulator` needs a space after `-e`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I was relying on that behavior of the kernel. I didn't realize `x-terminal-emulator` uses a non-standard option parser.

Comment: That's not non-standard (as if there was only one). If you run `x-terminal-emulator -ebash` from the command line, you'll see an error message that indicates that you passed it the equivalent of `-e -b -a -s -h`: "error: no such option: -a". Option combining is very common. In the shebang you posted, the kernel causes `x-terminal-emulator` to see _everything_ that follows as if it were a single quoted string. Try that at the command line and you'll see "error: no such option: -" which probably represents a bug in the error output. It should say "error: no such option: -ebash script.sh".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to what [Slax](https://www.slax.org)
developers do in their `bootinst.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#
#     If you see this file in a text editor instead of getting it executed,
#     then it is missing executable permissions (chmod). You can try to set
#     exec permissions for this file by using:  chmod a+x bootinst.sh
#
#     Scrolling down will reveal the actual code of this script.
#



# if we're running this from X, re-run the script in konsole or xterm
if [ "$DISPLAY" != "" ]; then
   if [ "$1" != "--rex" -a "$2" != "--rex" ]; then
      konsole --nofork -e /bin/sh $0 --rex 2>/dev/null || xterm -e /bin/sh $0 --rex 2>/dev/null || /bin/sh $0 --rex 2>/dev/null
      exit
   fi
fi

# put contents of your script here
echo hi

# do not close the terminal immediately, let user look at the results
echo "Press Enter..."
read junk
```

This script would run correctly both when started in graphical
environment and in tty.  It tries to restart the script inside
`konsole` and `xterm` and but if it doesn't find neither of them it
will simply run in the background.